# Unordered list jumps to other line

Tags: css

I'm creating a dropline web menu on JSFiddle. My question is how do I change the positioning the way menu appears on the same line. At the moment it drops below and starts a new line.

Example of my table http://jsfiddle.net/5jfsdwwu/17/

```
#menucontainer {
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100px;
    position;
    relative;
}
#menucontainer ul {
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
    list-style: none;
    width: 600px;
    height:40px;
}
/* Following selector will define the style for individual parent menu. The following style gives them a look when the menus are not selected.
note that the position proerty is not set.
*/
 #menucontainer ul li.parent_menu {
    list-style: none;
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 10px;
    background-color:#bc3030;
    display: inline;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    border-right: 3px solid #bc3030;
}
/* 
Style for the anchor tag defined in the parent. 
*/
 #menucontainer ul li.parent_menu a {
    margin-left: 10px;
    padding-left: 10px;
    margin-right: 10px;
    padding-right: 10px;
    background-color: #bc3030;
    display: inline;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-family:"Raleway";
    font-size: 15px;
    color: #333333;
    line-height: 50px;
}
/* The hover effect is defined using the below selectors
For the background-color opacity is used to create a semi-transperant look as a hover effect
*/
 #menucontainer ul li.parent_menu:hover {
    list-style: none;
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 10px;
    opacity:0 background-color:#bc3030;
    display: inline;
    border-right:3px solid #bc3030;
}
/*
The following class will define the style for anchor tag in the 

*/
 #menucontainer ul li.parent_menu:hover a {
    list-style: none;
    margin-left: 10px;
    padding-left: 10px;
    margin-right: 10px;
    padding-right: 10px;
    background-color: #bc3030;
    display: inline;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-family:"Raleway";
    font-size: 15px;
    color: #333333;
    line-height: 33px;
}
/***************SUB MENU***********************/

/*
Following class will hide the sub menu when the mouse is not hovering.
*/
 #menucontainer ul li.parent_menu ul {
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 10px;
    list-style: none;
    display:none;
    position: absolute;
    height: 0;
}
/*
Following class display hide the sub menu when the mouse is not hovering.
Note: for this style of the menu position is set to 'absolute'

*/
 #menucontainer ul li.parent_menu:hover ul {
    margin: -5px 0 0 0;
    padding: 0px;
    list-style: none;
    display:block;
    position: absolute;
    height: auto;
    width:100%;
    background-color:#333333;
}
/* Following selector will define the style for individual sub menu. The following style gives them a look when the menus are not selected.
note that the position proerty is not set and dispaly is block.
Also the float property is set left; This will keep the menu in a single line.
*/
 #menucontainer ul li.parent_menu:hover ul li.child_menu {
    list-style: none;
    margin-left: 10px;
    padding-left: 10px;
    margin-right: 10px;
    padding-right: 10px;
    display: block;
    float: left;
}
/*
Following class will define the style for the anchor tag of the submenu/child menu
*/
 #menucontainer ul li.parent_menu:hover li.child_menu a {
    padding-left: 10px;
    margin-right: 10px;
    padding-right: 10px;
    background-color:transparent;
    display: inline;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-family:"Raleway";
    font-size: 15px;
    color: #bc3030;
    line-height: 33px;
}
#menucontainer ul li.parent_menu:hover li.child_menu a:hover {
    margin-left: 10px;
    padding-left: 10px;
    margin-right: 10px;
    padding-right: 10px;
    background-color:transparent;
    display: inline;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-family:"Raleway";
    font-size: 15px;
    color: #FFFFFF;
    line-height: 33px;
}
```

Comment: Your list has a fixed width. Change it and it will work.

Comment: Where about have i fixed it?

Comment: Look into your CSS in line 14: width: 600px;

Comment: I think you may have some malformed HTML there...is the last "link" supposed to be a **separate** `ul`? - http://jsfiddle.net/5jfsdwwu/35/

Answer (score 0):

Your last menu option is in a seperate ul and your first ul has a fixed width of 600px

Bring that last item up into the first ul and then tamper with your width and you will have it